# MSAL Golang how to get user profile

Tags: go, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to integrate my Golang app with Azure using [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go). I created Azure app and I wrote  sample code to create public client . Below code worked.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go/apps/public"
)

func main() {
    publicClientApp, err := public.New("client_id", public.WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_The_Tenant_Name_Here"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(publicClientApp)
}
```

I would like to know how I can use this publicClientApp to get user profile. I could not find anything much in MSAL documentation

Answer (score -2):

I used Microsoft graph API to get the profile.